# separating column data into two new columns in a csv file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

Good day all,

I am writing into a csv file and I need to separate one column's information into two new columns
for example from this:

```
Call
Goku (1000)
```

To have something that looks like this:

```
Name  Landline
Goku  1000
```

so I need help on removing the brackets around the number and only taking the numbers inside it while renaming the Call column heading to Name and then create new column called Landline before writing the other columns, Name and Landline need to be the first two columns then the others follow.

I have the following code:

```
infile = "path to file"
outfile = "path to file"
def csv_wr():
# Opens output file for writing data into.
of = open(outfile, 'w')

# Reads the data from input file
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)

    count = 0

    # Writing data into output file.
    for row in data:

        # Converts the date column.
        mydate = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d %b %Y %H:%M: %S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


        x = ''.join(row['value'])

        # Inserting '0' value to empty columns.
        if len(x) < 1:
            value = 0
        else:
            value = row['value']

            # If statement inserting data with commas except for the last row into the output file.
            if count > 0:
                textline = ",\n('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')".format(row['call'], row['to'], mydate,
                                                                                   row['duration'], row['bill'],
                                                                                   value, row['status'])

            else:
                textline = "('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')".format(row['call'], row['to'], mydate,
                                                                                row['duration'], row['bill'],
                                                                                value, row['status'])
of.write(textline)
```

Comment: Any reason for not using [Text to Columns](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html)? You can replace all `)` with a blank, and specify that the delimiter is `(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to make use of a `csv.DictWriter()` to create your CSV file. The `call` field could be split using a regular expression to get the `name` and `landline` parts. This can then be added to the dictionary and written using the `.writerow()` call:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import re

in_file = 'input.csv'
out_file = 'output.csv'
fieldnames = ['date', 'name', 'landline', 'to', 'duration', 'bill', 'status']

with open(in_file, 'r', newline='') as f_input, open(out_file, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for row in csv_input:
        name, landline = re.match(r'(.*?) \((.*?)\)', row['call']).groups()
        row['name'] = name
        row['landline'] = landline
        row['date'] = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d %b %Y %H:%M: %S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I'm new to python so I had to read up on regular expressions to understand it but thank you very much this worked perfectly.